# decreasing the space between two divs

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have this format of divs with spans:

[image]

As you can see we have some space between the vertical divs. I want to reduce that space to get something like:
[image]

I tried negative padding and margin and it didn't work. Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" v-for="objData in data" :key="objData.label">
  <div class="column inline" style="background-color:grey;" >
    <span class="span hasan">{{objData.label}}</span>
    <span class="span">{{objData.value}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="vl"></div>
  <div class="column inline" style="background-color:grey;">
    <span class="span hasan">{{objData.label}}</span>
    <span class="span">{{objData.value}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<style>
.span {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.vl {
  display:inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 49%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.hasan {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: By "spacing between the vertical divs", do you mean the spacing between the 2 columns?

Comment: the the space between the rows. Like between "Hasan: asdads asdads" that are on top of each other.

Comment: The code you gave only contains 1 row.

Comment: Yes. I'm looping though an object. Each two arrays inside the object creates a row. We have 4 arrays so we got 2 rows here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, add this:

```
.row {
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

The row you added inside the html, it's margin-bottom can be removed by saying -20px or any other negative number you prefer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked thanks. However now the vertical line between columns `<div class="vl"></div>` sticks out of the bottom of the card. tried giving the line negative margin but didn't work. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by _vertical line_?